# How to remove starting(suffix) special character("_") from column names

Tags: r

Hi iam geeting "*" special character  suffix to the column names after dcast the data frame
like below
I want remove the "*" suffix from column names.

my colnames from df as follows

```
names(df)
  _a_code , b_code , c_code,_d_code_

trying to remove "_" suffix with below lines
 library(stringr)
names(df) <- str_replace(names(df), "_", "")

acode bcode , ccode, dcode

but i need

a_code , b_code , c_code, d_code_
```

Any modification required for above code
Thanks in advance

Comment: `gsub(pattern = "^_", replacement = "", v)` for `v <- c("_a_code", "b_code", "c_code", "_d_code_")`

Comment: Thanks @raymkchow : got with names(df) = stringi::stri_trim_left(names(df), "\\p{L}")